# Sort mongodb by two string values at the same time

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

For example I have schema like this below:

```
{
    "ID": "257185",
    "Name": "xxxx",
    "isAvailable": "NO",
    "isSuper": "NO"
}
```

I would like to sort it in mongo for values `isAvailable` and `isSuper` (string values) so the first record which I gonna recieve is YES / YES after that YES / NO or NO / YES.

How can I reach effect like this? Can I have any directions for that? I want to hide NO / NO records

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple `find` method using mongoose like this:

```
model.find({"$or": [
    {
      "isAvailable": "YES"
    },
    {
      "isSuper": "YES"
    }
  ]}).sort({isAvailable: -1,isSuper: -1})
```

Or if you are using an aggregation pipeline you can add these stages:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "$or": [
        {
          "isAvailable": "YES"
        },
        {
          "isSuper": "YES"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "$sort": {
      "isAvailable": -1,
      "isSuper": -1
    }
  }
])
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/jjCObVMsOGw)